# How to tap to click on FocalTechPS touchpad in Debian Stretch Gnome X11?

Tags: debian, x11, drivers, touchpad, focaltech

A touchpad or trackpad is a pointing device featuring a tactile sensor. 
I want to get *tap to click* work with FocalTechPS touchpad of ASUS laptop. 
Other natural features later: double-tap, ... 
In Fig. 1, you see that the system does not even notice Touchpad drivers, compare to Fig. 2 in the differential solution with *Wayland*.

Benchmark of the touchpad: one found in OS X in Mac devices since last five years

Fig. 1 Settings of Mouse and Touchpad in the OS when in X11

[image]

Doing `egrep -i 'synap|alps|etps|elan' /proc/bus/input/devices` based on the *SynapticsTouchpad* Debian documentation gives blank. Going the file manually through, I find the following.

```
I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0002 Product=0012 Version=0000
N: Name="FocalTechPS/2 FocalTech Touchpad"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio4/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio4/input/input12
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse0 event5 
B: PROP=5
B: EV=b
B: KEY=e520 10000 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=260800010000003
```

Maybe, related [here](https://github.com/mgottschlag/linux/commit/b2d84ebede586a171d0ec57d5a2036d83fd8e4bb). 
Bugs related in the application of the reverse engineered approaches [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1372609).
No integration in the kernel has been done yet, etc discussed [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/609930/25388).
No `focaltech-dkms` exists anymore, and not maintained.

Hardware: Asus Zenbook UX303UA R4028T
Touchpad: FocalTechPS
OS: Debian 9.1
Window manager: Gnome 3.22 on X11
Packages: `xserver-xorg-input-libinput`
Debian docs: [SynapticsTouchpad](https://wiki.debian.org/SynapticsTouchpad)
Related dev: Arch Linux [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=193593), Ubuntu 15.04 [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/609892/25388), private Github of mgottschlag [here](https://github.com/mgottschlag/linux/commit/b2d84ebede586a171d0ec57d5a2036d83fd8e4bb) but based on some version of `focaltech.h` headers not found anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move away from X11 and start to use [Wayland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayland_(display_server_protocol)). 
Tap to click work there.
Restart and Login Gnome with Wayland. 
You see there are significantly more features supported in Wayland of Fig. 2 than X11 of Fig. 1. 
Differences in usage

- two finger scrolling is opposite now than previously in X11, also shown as reseted *Natural Scrolling* setting. Set *Natural scrolling* of Fig. 2 to *off* to have equivalent settings as in Fig. 1.

Fig. 2 Debian Settings > Mouse and Touchpad in Wayland

[image]

Comment: Downvoter! Please, leave a feedback. - - I think a differential solution is essential when no solution has been existing for X11 driver issue for years. This comparison also helps to notice that the system of Fig. 1 does not even see Touchpad driver when comparing with Fig. 2.